# pre-loading content and display when needed

Tags: jquery, html

So I have some strings:

**HTML**

```
<p class='navLink' id='one'> div1 </p>
<p class='navLink' id='two'> div2 </p>
<p class='navLink' id='three'> div3 </p>


<div class='container'> </div>
```

Right now I am putting these divs into separate files and loading them on click:

**getDiv1.php**

```
<div class='div1' id='first'>
    <!--some la here-->
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$( '#one').on( 'click' , function() {

    $( '.container').fadeOut( 'fast' , function(){
        $( this).load( 'getDiv1.php' ) ;
    } ).delay( 500 ).fadeIn( 'slow' ) ;

} ) ;
```

I am trying to find a way to include all these into the DOM and display them on click.  They all display in the same area and take up the same space.  I have been playing around with `addClass` and `removeClass` but I cant get my head around the concept to get this working.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: plealse provide snippet code ...

Comment: Problem is that it works the way I am doing it, but I want to try and load all the data all at once so the display animations are smoother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide your divs by default and show them when links are clicked.

```js
$('.navLink').on('click', function() {

  $('.hidden-div').hide();

  var div_id = $(this).attr('id');
  $("#div-" + div_id).fadeIn('slow');

});
```

```css
.hidden-div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class='navLink' id='one'>div1</p>
<p class='navLink' id='two'>div2</p>
<p class='navLink' id='three'>div3</p>


<div class="hidden-div" id="div-one">
  div first
  <!--some la here-->
</div>

<div class="hidden-div" id="div-two">
  div second
  <!--some la here-->
</div>

<div class="hidden-div" id="div-three">
  div third
  <!--some la here-->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that is exactly what I was looking for.  I will let you know when I get back to my pc to test